# Firefox vs chrome uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token error

Tags: jquery, ajax

What the hell wrong with this function in google chrome, while it is working absolutely perfect in firefox,

```
function is_valid(type="") {
    if(type==""){
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=site_url('controller/function')?>"+'/'+type,
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
}
```

it always gives me a red line error in my firebug console, and breaks all my functionality,

```
uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token=
```

I am wondering that, why it is giving me an error, while every thing is perfectly working in firefox, i am using following jquery libraries,

```
<script src="path/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="path/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

here i call this,

```
<input name="my_type" onblur="is_valid($(this).val());" type="text" class="required />
```

Comment: Do you use PHP for that `url:`?

Comment: @dollarvar, php syntax was ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some `characters` can say `zero-space characters` which are not `shown`, try to delete the code and type again may solve your problem.

Also change your `function is_valid` like,

```
function is_valid(type) {// remove assignment of type from here
    if(typeof(type)==='undefined' || !type){
        return false;
    }
    ... remaining code
```

Comment: Thanx to all, i retyped as you said, and placed new checks as you mentioned, it is ok now, thanx again:)

Answer (score 2):

The method signature is invalid, you can't apply a default value like that

One possible solution is to check whether the value is a falsy value like, it will return of the value of type is `undefined`, `''`, `0`, NULL, etc

```
function is_valid(type) {
    if(!type){
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=site_url('controller/function')?>"+'/'+type,
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @IrfanAhmed may be your file is cached... try clearing your cache are refreshing

Comment: tried refreshing many times, but same error persist and giving me a warning as well, event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Note default values are allowed now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters